# AWS Lex V2 start-import

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-lex

I am migrating AWS Lex V2 chatbot. I have exported the Lex v2 model that I want to migrate an dit's in a zip file named DemoChatbot.zip. I have uploaded the DemoChatbot.zip in a s3 bucket called MyBucket. I have aws cli and terraform only on the migration machine, I am aware of the command called start-import. But I do not know how to use it. Can anyone please guide me?

I tried the regular build commands from AWS documentation, and it's creating the bot version 1, with no built on.  But that's not what I want. I need to migrate the lex v2 model using the DemoChatbot.zip (uploaded on s3 bucket).